# Bit shifting arithmetic explanation (C)

Tags: c

I have a homework problem that I know the answer to, but do not understand why it's the answer at all and just hoping to find someone that can explain it to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a = 0, b = 1, c;
    c = a << b + b << a;

    printf("d%\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

So the answer comes out so that C = '0'. I thought that 'a << b' would be equivalent to 0, 'b << a' would come out to 1, and so 'c = 0 + 1'. Why is this wrong?

And yet, when I try:

```
c = b << a + a << b
```

C equals '2'. Which makes even less sense to me. I would be so grateful if someone could explain to me why it works like this or point me to some reference that clarifies this behavior to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language grammar (or "operator precedence", if you will)  says that

```
c = a << b + b << a;
```

is actually

```
c = ((a << (b + b)) << a);
```

This expression shifts around the value of `a` and nothing else. Since the value of `a` is `0`, the result can't be anything else but `0`.

The same grouping tells you that

```
c = b << a + a << b;
```

is

```
c = ((b << (a + a)) << b);
```

which is

```
c = ((1 << 0) << 1);
```

And that's where that `2` came from.

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations. The operator `<<` has lower precedence than the operator `+`, so that:

- `0 << 1 + 1 << 0` is `0 << (1 + 1) << 0`, which is `0 << 2 << 0` which is of course `0`.
- `1 << 0 + 1 << 0` is `1 << (0 + 1) << 0`, which is `1 << 1 << 0` which is of course `2`.

Always use parentheses when in doubt, and even if not in doubt.

Comment: I wasn't given parenthesis in the question and apparently I don't know my order of operations as well as I thought I did. Thank you!